# run start.jar file button clicked. Apache Solr

Tags: java, apache, solr, jar

I want to run `start.jar` file, when `button` clicked, I find this,tried and  it work other `.jar` file

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folders/apache-solr-4.0.0/example/start.jar");
```

after this code, I look, `http://localhost:8983/solr/`, saw that, this code doesn't work for `start.jar`, what can I do?

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: didn't get error, but no reaction

Comment: Are you trying to invoke your jar through web browser, better you can write one servlet which will handle your request to invoke jar through browser.

Comment: You should try to launch it using the command line first to see if it works, also you should check that you can start it from everywhere, maybe you have to be at /Users/User/Desktop/Folders/apache-solr-4.0.0/example/